# How to access the cURL executable with Python subprocess module

Tags: python, windows, curl

I am trying to access the `curl` executable on my computer using a `subprocess` call, but when I do so, I get the following error:

`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

my code looks as follows

`path = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\Library\\bin\\curl.exe
subprocess.call([path])`

I know the path is correct, is there a reason that my script is balking at this?
As you can see, I am running the Anaconda2 Python Interpreter, not the standard one from Python.org

Comment: Check that `os.path.exists(path)` is true. I assume you're replacing `"UserName"` with the actual user name, but try to generalize this to arbitrary users. For example: `anaconda_path = os.path.join(os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'], 'Continuum', 'Anaconda2');` `curl_path = os.path.join(anaconda_path, 'Library', 'bin', 'curl.exe')`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a step back and do some sanity checks. Here are some steps to try.

- Copy the path in your script, and paste it into the file explorer (remove the escape characters) and verify that the path is indeed correct.
- Verify that you have proper permissions to the path
  <s>* Copy the executable (`curl.exe`) to a same location your python script is at, this eliminates the need to specify a path (sanity check)</s>

  `import subprocess`

  `path = 'curl.exe'`
  `subprocess.call([path])`

If this works, you can then move it your expected path and verify

Comment: `eryksun` is absolutely correct. I had written a quick test locally, which worked but I had curl in my path which of course is not true in the general case.